# mapping an array returns unresolved promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an array of values, and for each value i want to return an object that uses that value in a promise, i have the following code:

```
  const arr= serieses.map(async x => {
    const seriesId = await getSeriesIDFromName(x);
    return { part_id: partID, door_series_id: seriesId[0]["id"] };
  });
```

when i print arr after it all finished i get this

```
[
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]
```

But if i print each value before the return statment, i get what i need,

```
{ part_id: 1, door_series_id: 1 }
{ part_id: 1, door_series_id: 12 }
{ part_id: 1, door_series_id: 15 }
{ part_id: 1, door_series_id: 16 }
{ part_id: 1, door_series_id: 8 }
{ part_id: 1, door_series_id: 6 },
```

how do i get arr to holed those values, and the the promise object?

Comment: Just do `const values = await Promise.all(arr)`

Comment: Basically, async functions return promises. So you have to wait for all the promises to resolve to get the values.

Comment: @ClémentBerthou Thank you! it worked...
But i thought the await should wait for the promise to resolve, why do i nned to do the =Promise.all afte that as well?

Comment: Async functions return promises. So you mapper function returns a promise. So your map call return an array of promises.

await do not really wait, it is just syntaxical sugar over promises to make code reading and writing easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Promise.all()` for resolving all the promises in array, like this

```
const arr = serieses.map(async x => {
    const seriesId = await getSeriesIDFromName(x);
    return {part_id: partID, door_series_id: seriesId[0]["id"]};
});

const results = await Promise.all(arr)
```

`results` will contain an array with the values resolved from each promise

Comment: Thank you, but i though that this line:
`const seriesId = await getSeriesIDFromName(x);` 
waits for the promise to resolve and then the resolved value goes here:
`door_series_id: seriesId[0]["id"]`

why doesn't it?